# how to get a report of when internet connection was dropped

Tags: internet

I have always used PING command to monitor the internet connection and also check the response time. I want to monitor the connection over night and also want to get a report of when the connection was dropped, how many times etc.

Is there any free utility which can get me this rep port?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMCO has a free version of [Ping Monitor](http://www.emco.is/products/ping-monitor/feature-list.php) which works for up to 5 hosts. It has notification and reporting as well as varying data representations for filtering and sorting the data.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows systems, this can help: 
http://www.infixtechnologies.com/products/PingGraph/PingGraph.php